# Tradução de "litteris"

Tags: expressões, tradução, termos

A expressão latina *ipsis litteris* tem o significado de "com as mesmas palavras" ou algo parecido. No entanto, não consigo encontrar, nos dicionários de latim para português, a tradução de ***litteris*** para o português. O Google Tradutor traduz como "cartas", mas queria confirmar a veracidade dessa tradução.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[***Ipsis litteris***](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/05/ipsis-litteris/) significa ***com as mesmas letras***, ou seja, transcrito letra a letra com toda a exatidão. (O Google Tradutor também traduz o inglês *letters* apenas para *cartas*, esquecendo-se de *letras*.) Uma expressão relacionada e mais conhecida é *ipsis verbis*, que significa *com as mesmas palavras*.

[***Litteris***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/litteris) é o dativo plural e também o ablativo plural de [***littera***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/littera#Latin), plural *litterae*. (No latim a terminação das palavras altera-se de acordo com a função gramatical, como em português, por exemplo, se usa *tu* como sujeito e *te* como objeto.) ***Littera*** significa *letra, caligrafia* e (tipicamente no plural) *carta, literatura, livro, registo/registro, édito, decreto*.

Também em português, [***letra***](http://www.aulete.com.br/letra) pode significar *caligrafia*, e [***letras***](http://www.aulete.com.br/letras) pode significar *literatura, estudo de literatura e línguas*, e também já foi usado com o significado de *carta*.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, @Jacinto. Mas a minha principal dúvida é se a palavra latina **litteris**, sozinha, está correcta, e qual seria a tradução mais apropriada para o português. Seria "letras"?

Comment: Sozinho, seria *littera*, singular, ou *litterae*, plural, e pode significar *letra* e outras coisas. Espandi a resposta, e incluí um link